# How would you analyse two likert scales answered by the same people on several occasions?

Tags: correlation, survey, ordinal-data, likert, spearman-rho

I don't usually need to use stats in my work so this might seem like a basic question but, to me, it's baffling!

I have two questionnaires that I'm giving to the same group of people who are undergoing a treatment programme. Both are self-report measures; one on stress and one on quality of life. Both are Likert scales.

I'm not so interested in individual items but we want to find out whether people who score higher on stress take longer to complete the treatment. We also want to know if people who score higher on stress take longer to score higher quality of life.

After much Googling, I've seen Spearman's Rho suggested, which I kind of get for my first question about stress and length of time taken to treat, but I'm not sure. And I have no clue how to analyse the data to answer my second question about stress scores and quality of life scores. The same people would be answering the questionnaires at set intervals throughout treatment.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The second question is tricky because it involves three dimensions. Descriptively, you could consider Spearman's rank correlation between the two scores at different time points or different time lags (depending on the research question). A model with interaction between time and stress could be an option, but we need a bit more info.